# How to prevent local msmpi installation from loading system wide msmpi.dll

Tags: environment-variables, popen, hpc, cl, ms-mpi

I'm writing a console app for windows that sets up an environment and launches (popen) various hpc-apps using **msmpi mpiexec.exe**.

I have an **msmpi** installation installed locally to the application I'm writing. All works fine and parallel processing is OK.

However, as soon as I happen to have a system installation of msmpi *as well* (as installed by e.g. **msmpisetup.exe**), my applications stubbornly loads the **Windows/system32/msmpi.dll** instead of the **msmpi.dll** that I point at using PATH. Since the system msmpi.dll is of a different version, my apps does not run.

The **PATH** env.var. is set within my app, and it is apparently inherited correctly by the child processes, including **mpiexec**.

The only remedy I've found is to either (1) Rename **system32/msmpi.dll** or (2) place a copy of "my" **msmpi.dll** into every folder in which I have a parallel executable. Both remedies are... not nice.

How can I prevent my apps from selecting the system32/msmpi.dll and use the instance that's in the PATH instead??

Thank you for any advice.

N

Answer (score 0):

The standard DLL search order in Windows is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#standard-search-order-for-desktop-applications) to be

> 1. **The directory from which the application loaded.**
> 2. **The system directory.** Use the GetSystemDirectory function to get the path of this directory.
> 3. The 16-bit system directory. There is no function that obtains the path of this directory, but it is searched.
> 4. The Windows directory. Use the GetWindowsDirectory function to get the path of this directory.
> 5. The current directory.
> 6. **The directories that are listed in the PATH environment variable.** Note that this does not include the per-application path specified by the App Paths registry key. The App Paths key is not used when computing the DLL search path.

If you want your application to check a specific location first before using the system locations, you can call `SetDllDirectory` in the *parent* application before letting it execute other binaries that require a particular DLL.